# Reciving error on getWicketEventReference wicket 8

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea, wicket, wicket-8

I receiving an error that the getWicketEventReference method does not exist and cannot find the symbol, the error:
cannot find symbol
symbol:   method getWicketEventReference()
location: class org.apache.wicket.settings.JavaScriptLibrarySettings
[image]

Comment: If the compilation fails, you project is likely missing some dependency. Make sure all the required jars are present and the libraries your project uses are added in `pom.xml` dependencies. Since the issue occurs on Maven build, the issue has nothing to do with IntelliJ IDEA and you should not set this tag in your question.

Answer (score 0):

wicket-event.js has been merged into wicket-ajax.js for Wicket 9.0.0, I believe.

So, you can safely remove this line!